# Metronic Tooltip not working

Tags: tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, metronic

I am using the metronic 5 and I tried to add tooltip with `data-toggle="m-tooltip"` with `title="Some Title"`

When the page is rendered and I hover on the element, the tooltip is triggered, but a class `show` is not added to the tooltip which is required to add `opacity:1` to the element and get the element into view.

Can anyone suggest any change or Am I missing any script?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you initialize the tooltips on your page?

```
$(function () 
{
     $('[data-toggle="m-tooltip"]').tooltip()
 });
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

Comment: I managed to get it to work using the same solution. Thanks for the help.